# How do I order a column in SQL Server in following manner?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to order by a column which has a data type of `nvarchar`. My column data looks like this:

```
9 AM - 11 AM
1 PM - 3 PM
11 AM - 1 PM
3 PM - 5 PM
5 PM - 7 PM
```

And I want to order by my column in this manner:

```
9 AM - 11 AM
11 AM - 1 PM
1 PM - 3 PM
3 PM - 5 PM
5 PM - 7 PM
```

How can I do this?

Comment: add new column, with sorting number and sort by it

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why in the world are you storing those same values over and over??? You desperately need to read about normalization. That should be a foreign key in a table that holds those values. Then you could easily add a SortOrder column in your reference table and the problem is simple to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
declare @t1 table(col1 varchar(50))
insert into @t1 values
('9 AM - 11 AM')
,('1 PM - 3 PM')
,('11 AM - 1 PM')
,('3 PM - 5 PM')
,('5 PM - 7 PM')
SELECT row_number() OVER (
        ORDER BY cast(substring(col1, 0, charindex('-', col1)) AS TIME)
        ) rn
    ,col1
FROM @t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable that contains the items in the sort order you want separated by a character that doesn't occur in your data. When I have done this before I have used the tilde ("~") character. It would look something like this...

```
DECLARE @CustomSortOrder VARCHAR(100)

SET @CustomSortOrder = '9 AM - 11 AM~11 AM - 1 PM~1 PM - 3 PM~3 PM - 5 PM~5 PM - 7 PM~'

SELECT *
FROM [YourTable]
ORDER BY CHARINDEX([YourTable].[YourColumn] + '~', @CustomSortOrder)
```

For this scenario you could probably do without the tilde separator. However, I like it there anyway to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Note this is not going to be efficient and VERY error prone - you should seriously consider storing those values as real times.
I'm using a table variable with one column called [timen] to store your values.
Get the ASCII value for the second to last character and add it to whatever the value left of the space in the string:

```
    DECLARE @timetable TABLE(timen nvarchar(5));
    INSERT INTO @timetable(timen)
        VALUES ('9 AM'), ('11 AM'), ('1 PM'), ('3 PM'), ('11 AM'), ('1 PM'), ('3 PM'), ('5 PM'), ('5 PM'), ('7 PM');
    SELECT  t.timen
    FROM    @timetable t
    ORDER BY LEFT(t.timen, (PATINDEX('% %', t.timen) - 1)) + ASCII(SUBSTRING(RIGHT(t.timen, 2), 1, 1));
```